# How can I get multiple attributes from XML file?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an XML file:

```
<One>
  <Document Count="1">
    <Customer Id="1" Type="0"/>
    <Passengers>
      <Passenger Seq="1" Id="13" Name="Test Name"/>
      <Passenger Seq="2" Id="14" Name="Test Name4"/>
    </Passengers>
  </Document>
  <Document Count="2">
    <Customer Id="2" Type="0"/>
    <Passengers>
      <Passenger Seq="1" Id="16" Name="Test Name10"/>
      <Passenger Seq="2" Id="18" Name="Test Name30"/>
    </Passengers>
  </Document>
</One>
...
<Two>
  <Document Count="1">
    <User Id="1" Type="0"/>
    <Passengers>
      <Passenger Seq="1" Id="123" Name="Test Name"/>
      <Passenger Seq="2" Id="124" Name="Test Name2"/>
    </Passengers>
  </Document>
  <Document Count="2">
    <Customer Id="2" Type="0"/>
    <Passengers>
      <Passenger Seq="1" Id="1130" Name="Test Name123"/>
      <Passenger Seq="2" Id="1131" Name="Test Name34342"/>
    </Passengers>
  </Document>
</Two>
```

My steps:

```
array = []
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(file.xml))    
doc_pass = doc.xpath("//Document//Passengers//Passenger")    
doc_pass.each do |pass|
  hash = {}
  hash[:id] = pass['Name'] #???
  array << hash  
end
```

I want to get all attributes like `Id`, `Name` from Passengers, and create a hash with all passengers. 
Example:

```
[{ :id => '13', :name => "Test Name"}, { :id => '14', :name => "Test Name4"}, { :id => '16', :name => "Test Name10"}, { :id => '18', :name => "Test Name30"}, { :id => '123', :name => "Test Name"} ... ]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Don't use `"//Document//Passengers//Passenger"`. The correct XPath would be `"//Document/Passengers/Passenger"`. `//` means "find it anywhere starting at the root" so you're repeatedly telling the parser to start its search over.

Comment: The XML sample is malformed. XML requires a single root node and you have two.

Comment: Do you want to get all the attributes, or specific ones? If the attributes change do you want the code to dynamically reflect that, or should the code be static and have to be manually adjusted to pick up the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the line

```
  hash[:id] = pass['Name'] #???
```

with

```
  hash[:id] = pass['Id']
  hash[:name] = pass['Name']
```

and it will work, as long as you have a valid XML file.

The XML fragment in your question is not valid for two reasons:

- The `...` between `<One>` and `<Two>` (I guess that's intentional and not a problem with your real data)
- Your XML does not have a root element. Currently you have two "roots", the elements `<One>` and `<Two>`. If that's how your real XML file is composed, I think Nokogiri will only read the first node.

Comment: You are right. Actually all work fine. I did error in my script, but on stackoverflow I wrote all correct.

Comment: "Your XML does not have a root element. Currently you have two "roots", the elements <One> and <Two>." That's because the XML is malformed. XML requires a root node.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing that you specify the attributes manually in your code. In case you want to get ALL of the attributes in the format you specified, try this:

```
array = []
Nokogiri::XML(File.open(file.xml)).xpath("//Document//Passengers//Passenger").each do |x|
  hash = {}
  x.attributes.each do |attribute| # loop through all attributes in the matches found
    hash[attribute[1].name.to_sym] = attribute[1].value
  end
  array << hash
end
```

`array` should have this value:

```
[{:Seq=>"1", :Id=>"13", :Name=>"Test Name"}, {:Seq=>"2", :Id=>"14", :Name=>"Test Name4"}, {:Seq=>"1", :Id=>"16", :Name=>"Test Name10"}, {:Seq=>"2", :Id=>"18", :Name=>"Test Name30"}]
```

Comment: Thank you. I found the correct answer on my issue at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<xml>
<One>
  <Document Count="1">
    <Customer Id="1" Type="0"/>
    <Passengers>
      <Passenger Seq="1" Id="13" Name="Test Name"/>
      <Passenger Seq="2" Id="14" Name="Test Name4"/>
    </Passengers>
  </Document>
  <Document Count="2">
    <Customer Id="2" Type="0"/>
    <Passengers>
      <Passenger Seq="1" Id="16" Name="Test Name10"/>
      <Passenger Seq="2" Id="18" Name="Test Name30"/>
    </Passengers>
  </Document>
</One>

<Two>
  <Document Count="1">
    <User Id="1" Type="0"/>
    <Passengers>
      <Passenger Seq="1" Id="123" Name="Test Name"/>
      <Passenger Seq="2" Id="124" Name="Test Name2"/>
    </Passengers>
  </Document>
  <Document Count="2">
    <Customer Id="2" Type="0"/>
    <Passengers>
      <Passenger Seq="1" Id="1130" Name="Test Name123"/>
      <Passenger Seq="2" Id="1131" Name="Test Name34342"/>
    </Passengers>
  </Document>
</Two>
</xml>
EOT
```

Here's how to find all `<Passenger>` nodes and grab their data:

```
array = doc.search('Passenger').map{ |node| 
  {
    id: node['Id'],
    name: node['Name']
  }
}
```

Here's what `array` looks like:

```
array
# => [{:id=>"13", :name=>"Test Name"},
#     {:id=>"14", :name=>"Test Name4"},
#     {:id=>"16", :name=>"Test Name10"},
#     {:id=>"18", :name=>"Test Name30"},
#     {:id=>"123", :name=>"Test Name"},
#     {:id=>"124", :name=>"Test Name2"},
#     {:id=>"1130", :name=>"Test Name123"},
#     {:id=>"1131", :name=>"Test Name34342"}]
```

I'm using a CSS selector. Because I wanted all the "Passenger" nodes, then search becomes easy and doesn't require drilling down through the chain of parent nodes.

An array of hashes is awkward to use/reuse though. I'd recommend using a regular hash if there is no chance of collisions in `:id`:

```
hash = doc.search('Passenger').map{ |node| [node['Id'], node['Name']] }.to_h

hash
# => {"13"=>"Test Name",
#     "14"=>"Test Name4",
#     "16"=>"Test Name10",
#     "18"=>"Test Name30",
#     "123"=>"Test Name",
#     "124"=>"Test Name2",
#     "1130"=>"Test Name123",
#     "1131"=>"Test Name34342"}
```

If you need to dynamically track all the parameters for Passenger nodes, whenever new ones are added or old ones deleted:

```
hash = doc.search('Passenger').map{ |node| 
  [
    node['Id'], 
    node.attribute_nodes.map{ |a| 
      [a.name, a.value] 
    }.to_h 
  ] 
}.to_h

hash
# => {"13"=>{"Seq"=>"1", "Id"=>"13", "Name"=>"Test Name"},
#     "14"=>{"Seq"=>"2", "Id"=>"14", "Name"=>"Test Name4"},
#     "16"=>{"Seq"=>"1", "Id"=>"16", "Name"=>"Test Name10"},
#     "18"=>{"Seq"=>"2", "Id"=>"18", "Name"=>"Test Name30"},
#     "123"=>{"Seq"=>"1", "Id"=>"123", "Name"=>"Test Name"},
#     "124"=>{"Seq"=>"2", "Id"=>"124", "Name"=>"Test Name2"},
#     "1130"=>{"Seq"=>"1", "Id"=>"1130", "Name"=>"Test Name123"},
#     "1131"=>{"Seq"=>"2", "Id"=>"1131", "Name"=>"Test Name34342"}}
```

Basically that'll create a hash representation of the node, which can be good or bad, depending on what you're trying to do with the data.

Comment: Thank you! This method helped me to remove many strings in my script.

Comment: Parsing XML/HTML can be bewildering at first. I find using the CSS selectors to be easier because they're more readable, though XPath is more capable. It's OK to bounce back and forth between them in your code.